# group_concat and group by are NOT working together

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have looked for the answer, but I couldn't find, so hopefully you can help me. 
I'm trying to get a list of jobs grouped by 'vacatureID' and 'organisatieID'.
But I can only get one of them to work.

Could someone please advise?

Thanks.

```
SELECT 

    tblVacature.vacatureNaam, 
    tblVacature.vacatureCode, 
    DATE_FORMAT(tblVacature.vacatureDatumToegevoegd,'%d-%m'), 
    MAX(tblVacature.vacatureSuper), 

    tblOrganisatie.organisatieID, 
    tblOrganisatie.organisatieNaam, 
    tblOrganisatie.organisatieNaamConvert, 

    GROUP_CONCAT(tblSpecialisme.specialismeNaam 
        ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN specialismeNaam = 'BLABLA' 
        THEN 1 WHEN specialismeNaam = 'BLABLA 2' 
        THEN 2 WHEN specialismeID = '0' 
        THEN 4 ELSE 3 END, specialismeNaam ASC) AS specialismeNamen, 

    GROUP_CONCAT(tblSpecialisme.specialismeNaamConvert 
        ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN specialismeNaam = 'BLABLA' 
        THEN 1 WHEN specialismeNaam = 'BLABLA 2' 
        THEN 2 WHEN specialismeID = '0' 
        THEN 4 ELSE 3 END, specialismeNaam ASC) AS specialismeNamenConvert 

FROM tblVacature 
LEFT JOIN tblOrganisatie ON (tblVacature.vacatureOrganisatie = tblOrganisatie.organisatieID) 
LEFT JOIN tblSpecialisme ON FIND_IN_SET(tblSpecialisme.specialismeID, REPLACE(tblVacature.vacatureSpecialisme, ' ', ',')) 

WHERE 

    vacatureActive = '1' 
    AND vacatureDatumToegevoegd <= ? 

GROUP BY vacatureID, organisatieID 
ORDER BY MAX(vacatureSuper) DESC, tblVacature.vacatureDatumToegevoegd DESC
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data, make a sqlfiddle, and explain what result you're hoping to achive with it?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I would like to have a short list where every 'tblOrganisatie.organisatieID' only appears once. With the currect query I get a long list with multiple jobs (vacatures) per 'tblOrganisatie.organisatieID'.

Comment: Since you're grouping by two fields, you get a row for each unique combination of the fields. If you just want one row for each `organisatieID`, then take `vacatureID` out of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: When I remove the `organisatieID` the `GROUP_CONCAT` shows multiple values from all the jobs, not just from the job itself.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblSpecialisme.specialismeNaam ...)` to suppress duplicates.

Comment: Yes, this removes the duplicates, but I still get all the values of the other jobs from the same `organisatieID`. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you're only grouping by organisatieID, not splitting it up by vacatureID. You said you only want each organisatieID to appear once, so everything has to go in there. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired results, like I asked earlier. I can't understand what you're trying to achieve from just your questions.

Comment: organisatieID 1 - most recent job (specialismeNaam 1, specialismeNaam 2, specialismeNaam 3 etc.)
organisatieID 2 - most recent job (specialismeNaam 1, specialismeNaam 2, specialismeNaam 3 etc.)
organisatieID 3 - most recent job (specialismeNaam 1, specialismeNaam 2, specialismeNaam 3 etc.)
organisatieID 4 - most recent job (specialismeNaam 1, specialismeNaam 2, specialismeNaam 3 etc.)

Comment: Either make a sqlfiddle or stop wasting my time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how. But thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Go to sqlfiddle.com and enter some data. Post the link here.